# How to list all available versions of a Google API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm trying to use a Google API for a project, but I have a problem ;

Sometimes, there are versions like v1beta, v4.3, v2alpha2.5 etc, guessable but I don't want to bruteforce it to find the versions.

So I was wondering, how to list all available versions of an API without using the endpoint https://discovery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis ?
Like a parameter for all individual APIs, would be cool to have a `<api>.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest/versions`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with Google and Google Cloud APIs for more than a decade. There is no shortcut that I know of. Google does not publicize all API versions.

Knowing all available API versions will not do you any good in most cases. Some API versions require prior approval (whitelisting) to use them. Others might be in **alpha** status and should not be used except in certain situations. Some API versions require a relationship with the PM to obtain details. Some API versions require an NDA for either the API, the service, or both.

For the APIs that you require, subscribe to or follow the blogs and release notes.

Unless you have a specific requirement, only use the latest production (GA) version. GA versions have published documentation detailing the interface, methods, and parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your informations John.
What do you mean by "PM" ?
And I think the "NDA" you're talking about is a Non Disclosure Act ?

Comment: 1) In this use case **PM** means Product Manager. There are also Program Managers. In Google Cloud Product Managers spend time getting the word out (product marketing), supporting early adopters and they usually work long hours helping make a product/service succeed. Getting the support of a PM is a good step that brings lots of benefits. 2) NDA means Non-Disclosure Agreement. I have been part of many programs that require an NDA to obtain details on a new service. Typically, this is before **alpha** is released. These programs are hard to get into.

Comment: @mxrch 3) There is another program called **Insiders** that is open to most customers. Invitations for access to new services or the next generation of an existing service often appear on the Insiders group. 4) Then there are Google Groups. Many of the Google Cloud services have their own group that you can join. An example is **Google Cloud Functions PHP Testers**. https://groups.google.com/